# C# Protractor angular never provided resumeBootstrap

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, protractor-net

This is my first stackoverflow question. I already searched for some answers on this site, but all the solutions I found didn't worked for me, or they were meant for Java or javascript.

**The situation**

As a junior automation tester I created a sort of Automation Test Framework in C# with the Selenium Webdriver and Protractor.Net.
The Framework consists of 2 parts.

1. The page objects
2. The tests

There is also a page object base class. In this class I defined methods that are used by every page object, such as a method for opening a specific program module.
In the tests, there is also a base class. In this class the Test attributes (C# UnitTest) are defined, such as TestInitialize, TestCleanup, AssemblyCleanup.

In the Test Base class I also defined the NgWebDriver, ChromeDriver:

```
driver = new NgWebDriver(new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver());
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

In the Page Object Base class I defined a method to open a specific part of the 
website:

```
public void OpenSPA(string spa)
    {                      
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(spa, true);
        driver.Navigate().Refresh();

    }
```

The pararmeter spa contains the url to navigate to.

**The Testcase**

The testcase is just simple:
 open module x of the website
module x is just an url

The complete code of the testcase:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory(cat), TestCategory(regression)]
public void Organisatie_CheckActief()
{
    bool is_actief;

    var organisatie = new CrmSPA(driver);

    organisatie.VulVeld("Vrij zoeken", "XXXX");
    is_actief = organisatie.IsRelatieActief();

    //Assertion
    Assert.IsTrue(is_actief == true, "Relatie is niet actief.");
```

**The problem:**
Since a couple of weeks ago I get the following error when running the testcase:

```
Test Name:  Organisatie_CheckActief
Test FullName:  FirstTest.Webdrivers.WijzigenOrganisatie_Basis.Organisatie_CheckActief
Test Source:    C:\Users\XXXX\TestCases\\Organisatie\WijzigenOrganisatie_basis.cs : line 168
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:41,1353784
```

Result StackTrace:

```
bij OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   bij OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   bij OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   bij OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteAsyncScript(String script, Object[] args)
   bij Protractor.NgWebDriver.set_Url(String value) in c:\Users\Bruno\Projets\GitHub\bbaia\protractor-net\src\Protractor\NgWebDriver.cs:regel 163
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    bij Protractor.NgWebDriver.set_Url(String value) in c:\Users\Bruno\Projets\GitHub\bbaia\protractor-net\src\Protractor\NgWebDriver.cs:regel 193
   bij Protractor.NgNavigation.GoToUrl(String url, Boolean ensureAngularApp) in c:\Users\Bruno\Projets\GitHub\bbaia\protractor-net\src\Protractor\NgNavigation.cs:regel 112
   bij FirstTest.PageObjects.BaseSPA.OpenSPA(String spa) in C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\\\FirstTest\PageObjects\BaseSPA.cs:regel 55
   bij FirstTest.PageObjects.CrmSPA.CrmSPA..ctor(NgWebDriver driver) in C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\\\FirstTest\PageObjects\CRM\CrmSPA\CrmSPA.cs:regel 37
   bij FirstTest.Webdrivers.WijzigenOrganisatie_Basis.Organisatie_CheckActief() in C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\\\FirstTest\TestCases\RelatieSPA\Organisatie\WijzigenOrganisatie_basis.cs:regel 174
Result Message: 
Test method FirstTest.Webdrivers.WijzigenOrganisatie_Basis.Organisatie_CheckActief threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: **Angular could not be found on the page** 'https://XXXXX/CRM/Relaties/ ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

The Result on screen/browser

When running the test the following happens:

1. the chrome browser starts (OK)
2. the chrome browser opens maximized (ok)
3. the chrome browser gets the url (ok)
4. the browser is empty shows blank page (NOK)

somehow i found the following error:
angular never provided resumeBootstrap

I searched on google and stackoverflow and i tried some answers like the synchronize option:
*driver.IgnoreSynchronization*
the problem does not always shows up. sometimes the page is loaded and the test continues. 
I already tried to reinstall protractor-net, a newer chromedriver and seleniumdriver. The problem still exist.

If anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
```

...implies that the *RemoteWebDriver* incurred an error while executing a command.

Selenium being an open source framework, you can have a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote).

**`GoToUrl()`** is defined in [RemoteNavigator.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteNavigator.cs) and accepts only one argument **`string url`** as follows :

```
    /// Navigate to a url for your test
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">String of where you want the browser to go to</param>
    public void GoToUrl(string url)
    {
        this.driver.Url = url;
    }
```

But in your code block while invoking `GoToUrl()` method along with the `string` **spa** you have also passed **true**. This possibly raises the error.

### Solution

Within `GoToUrl()` method removing the argument **true** will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggested solution: removing true in the method.
But it didn't worked. Still some tests are working (opening the url/page), and some shows a blank page.

For your information: when I hover over GoToUrl, the following hovertext is shown: void.Ngnavigation.GoToUrl(string url)(+3 overloads).
So it is using the method from NgWebdriver. That's why I also used the parameter **true** first time.